# How to filter a Pandas series while writing to list

Tags: python, pandas

For a given column `'A'` in a pandas dataframe `'tbl'`, I have been trying to write the column `.tolist()` and filter out the items that are `'.'`. This works, but doesn't seem very readable:

`list_of_A = tbl['A'][~tbl['A'].isin(['.'])].tolist()`

Also, checking a list of one seems needlessly slow, though `str.contains('.')` seems like it would be slower due to pattern matching. Am I missing a better method?

**Update:**
@jpp, @piRSquared and @Scott-Boston all had good methods, so it came down to a test:

```
>>> tbl = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50000, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
>>> tbl.loc[tbl.sample(10000).index, 'A'] = '.'
>>> min(timeit.repeat("list_of_A = tbl.loc[tbl['A'].ne('.'), 'A'].tolist()", repeat=1000, number=100, globals=globals()))
0.37328900000102294
>>> min(timeit.repeat("list_of_A = tbl.A.values[tbl.A.values != '.'].tolist()", repeat=1000, number=100, globals=globals()))
0.1470019999997021
>>> min(timeit.repeat("tbl.query('A != \".\"')['A'].tolist()", repeat=1000, number=100, globals=globals()))
0.45748099999946135
```

Discovering `.loc` has opened up a world of possibilities for me, but to smash 'n' grab a filtered column list, looks like converting to an ndarray is fastest.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/17071871/2336654

Comment: @dragon951, did one of the below solutions help? if so, feel free to accept (tick on left).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension

```
list_of_A = [x for x in df['A'] if x != '.']
```

Probably more performant

```
list_of_A = [x for x in df['A'].values.tolist() if x != '.']
```

Faster still

```
tbl.A.values[tbl.A.values != '.'].tolist()
```

Comment: So `.values` returns an ndarray of the series, but does the [] slice the first array by the subset array? I don't understand the operation that is happening.

Comment: @dragon951 yes.  Inside the [] is a Boolean array of equal to the series. This is called Boolean slicing and will leave you with an array of values coinciding with where those values are not equal to “.”

Answer (score 2):

Two things to note:

- Chained indexing is [explicitly discouraged](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy); avoid as it is never necessary.
- `isin` is only recommended if you are comparing to a `list` / `set` / `pd.Series`. `loc` accessor with `==` operator should be sufficient.

Try this instead:

```
list_of_A = tbl.loc[~(tbl['A'] == '.'), 'A'].tolist()
```

As @BradSolomon points out, there is an alternative:

```
list_of_A = tbl.loc[tbl['A'].ne('.'), 'A'].tolist()
```

Comment: Or: `tbl.loc[tbl.A.ne('.'), 'A'].tolist()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `query` for more readability:

```
tbl.query('A != "."')['A'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a temporary variable and two lines of code makes this more readable:

```
exclude   = tbl['A'].isin(['.'])
list_of_A = tbl['A'][~exclude].tolist()
```